# Filtering / sorting properties into a map in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to read Java system properties at runtime, filter based on an `includes` list *(hard coded here but normally injected in via properties file)* and finally sorted by key and converted to a `Map<String, String>`.  This is what I've come up with but not sure if it's the most elegant solution.

```java
final List<String> includes = Arrays
    .asList("java.version", "PID", "os.name", "user.country");     // hard coded here but (usually defined in a properties file)

Map<String, String> systemMap = System.getProperties()
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(s -> includes != null && includes.contains(s.getKey()))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
        Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.comparing(e -> (String) e))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> (String) e.getKey(), 
        e -> (String) e.getValue(),
        (e1, e2) -> e2, 
        LinkedHashMap::new)
    );
```

I'm keen to know if the code can be tidied up.

Comment: You don't have to do this each time `includes != null && includes.contains(s.getKey()`. If `includes == null` you seem to drop all properties, so check that first and `return`.

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.comparing(e -> (String) e)` is awful, use [`Map.Entry.comparingByKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey--).

Comment: You can cast to `Map.Entry<String, String>` once to avoid the rest of the casting.

Comment: Converting to LinkedHashMap (can) destroy effect of sorting, class not guarantee sorting. But TreeMap provide sorting 'for free'

Comment: @JacekCz wrong. `LinkedHashMap` guarantees insertion order.

Comment: @BoristheSpider lamba can be parallelized /reordered and had not guarantee of order

Comment: It's a **sorted** `Stream` @JacekCz. This is nonsense. If a sorted stream didn't gurantee order it would be most useless.

Comment: @BoristheSpider agree, my eyes ommit details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about reversing it and using a `stream` of the `includes` list instead? This way, you don't have to unpack those map entries all the time, you can just use `sorted`, and if `includes` only includes valid properties, you might not even need the `filter`. (Also, lookup in the map is faster than lookup in the list, but that probably does not matter much.)

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
Map<String, String> systemMap = includes.stream()
    .filter(props::containsKey)
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, props::getProperty,
        (e1, e2) -> e2, 
        LinkedHashMap::new)
    );
```

Comment: I really like this answer - it (a) reads well and is very clear, (b) efficient as its streaming over a sub list (i.e. the `includes` list).  The `filter` here really should mostly be true but will avoid potential nulls.  Thanks!

Comment: Since this solution allows to store the properties in the order found in the `includes` list, you can provide a sorted list in the first place, eliminating the need to sort it at runtime. Even doing an `includes.sort(null)` once before the stream operation might be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion, get all properties (about 100) to filter 4 is suboptimal.

My proposal is:

```
// hard coded here but (usually defined in a properties file)
final List<String> includes = Arrays.asList("java.version", "PID",
    "os.name", "user.country");

Map<String, String> systemMap = includes.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e,
        e -> System.getProperty(e)));
```

UPDATE: sorted version

```
final List<String> includes = Arrays.asList("java.version", "PID",
    "os.name", "user.country");     
Map<String, String> systemMap = includes.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e,
        e -> System.getProperty(e),
        (e1, e2) -> e2, 
        TreeMap::new));
return systemMap;
```

Comment: This does neither filter, nor create a sorted map.

Comment: lambda filtering is not required. I'm not religious 'lamba programmer', filter is done at System level. Hope understand core of question. Agree,

Comment: What do you mean, "filter is done at system level"? What if there are values in `include` that are not valid properties? Not sue if this can be the case, but you should at least mention this possibility.

Comment: `System` class with big 'S', `getProperty(String)` method. All answers have problem when some strange exceptions breaks (I understand "wrong property"), my answer too

Comment: I agree with this - just pull the ones you want rather than exclude the ones you don't. You could event just `sort` `includes` to avoid all the sorting, `TreeMap` nonsense.

Comment: Among these four example keys, `"PID"` is not guaranteed to be present (e.g. it is not in Windows). While the other solutions remove this key, either due to the `filter` step or implicitly by iterating the existing properties, your solution will produce a `NullPointerException`. This has nothing to do with “some strange exceptions”, but is perfectly predictable and well documented behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The "good" part here is that `Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object>` which is a source of problems. Unsurprisingly, the `System.getProperties().entrySet()` returns a `Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>>`.

Therefore, we need one additional mapping operation to turn each `Entry<Object, Object>` into a `Entry<String, String>` before we move on to filtering and sorting:

```
final Map<String, String> map = System.getProperties()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue().toString()))
        .filter(e -> includes.contains(e.getKey()))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

The method references look vague, so the last 2 operations would use shorter lambda expressions:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey()))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

---

Another option is iterating over the `includes` list which seems to be smaller than the `System.getProperties()`:

```
final Properties properties = System.getProperties();
final Map<String, String> map2 = includes
        .stream()
        .filter(properties::containsKey)
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), properties::getProperty));
```

Comment: Since `Collection.contains(Object)` doesn’t require the argument to have the element type, you can do `.filter(e -> includes.contains(e.getKey()))` *before* the `map` step, saving a lot of work, further, you can shorten the code to `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())` and `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))`